# @Slf4j logger not working after updating to 2.16.0 version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, slf4j

I am not able to run the project after updating the version for log4j to

```
<log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>
```

to update the version of log4j used in

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I upgraded it to fix the CVE-2021-44228 issue
but now I am getting this error

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:52737,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\ThinkBook\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.2\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\ThinkBook\Documents\git\back-end\epharmacy-backend\impl\target\classes;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jakarta.el\3.0.3\jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.1.7.Final\hibernate-validator-6.1.7.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.0.12.RELEASE\thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\ognl\ognl\3.1.26\ognl-3.1.26.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.20.0-GA\javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\attoparser\attoparser\2.0.5.RELEASE\attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\xhtmlrenderer\flying-saucer-core\9.1.20\flying-saucer-core-9.1.20.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\xhtmlrenderer\flying-saucer-pdf-itext5\9.1.20\flying-saucer-pdf-itext5-9.1.20.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\itextpdf\itextpdf\5.5.11\itextpdf-5.5.11.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.19\byte-buddy-1.10.19.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\pdfbox\2.0.22\pdfbox-2.0.22.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\fontbox\2.0.22\fontbox-2.0.22.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\firebase\firebase-admin\6.8.0\firebase-admin-6.8.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api-client\google-api-client-gson\1.25.0\google-api-client-gson-1.25.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\http-client\google-http-client-gson\1.25.0\google-http-client-gson-1.25.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\http-client\google-http-client\1.25.0\google-http-client-1.25.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.13\httpclient-4.5.13.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.14\httpcore-4.4.14.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.1\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api\api-common\1.7.0\api-common-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\auth\google-auth-library-oauth2-http\0.11.0\google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.11.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\auth\google-auth-library-credentials\0.11.0\google-auth-library-credentials-0.11.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\cloud\google-cloud-storage\1.43.0\google-cloud-storage-1.43.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\cloud\google-cloud-core\1.43.0\google-cloud-core-1.43.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api\gax\1.30.0\gax-1.30.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java-util\3.6.0\protobuf-java-util-3.6.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api\grpc\proto-google-common-protos\1.12.0\proto-google-common-protos-1.12.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api\grpc\proto-google-iam-v1\0.12.0\proto-google-iam-v1-0.12.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\cloud\google-cloud-core-http\1.43.0\google-cloud-core-http-1.43.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\http-client\google-http-client-appengine\1.24.1\google-http-client-appengine-1.24.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\http-client\google-http-client-jackson\1.24.1\google-http-client-jackson-1.24.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api\gax-httpjson\0.47.0\gax-httpjson-0.47.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\opencensus\opencensus-contrib-http-util\0.15.0\opencensus-contrib-http-util-0.15.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\apis\google-api-services-storage\v1-rev135-1.24.1\google-api-services-storage-v1-rev135-1.24.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\cloud\google-cloud-firestore\0.61.0-beta\google-cloud-firestore-0.61.0-beta.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\cloud\google-cloud-core-grpc\1.43.0\google-cloud-core-grpc-1.43.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\3.6.0\protobuf-java-3.6.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-protobuf\1.13.1\grpc-protobuf-1.13.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-protobuf-lite\1.13.1\grpc-protobuf-lite-1.13.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-context\1.13.1\grpc-context-1.13.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api\gax-grpc\1.30.0\gax-grpc-1.30.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\threeten\threetenbp\1.3.3\threetenbp-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api\grpc\proto-google-cloud-firestore-v1beta1\0.26.0\proto-google-cloud-firestore-v1beta1-0.26.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\auto\value\auto-value\1.4\auto-value-1.4.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-netty-shaded\1.13.1\grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-core\1.13.1\grpc-core-1.13.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.1.2\error_prone_annotations-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\opencensus\opencensus-contrib-grpc-metrics\0.12.3\opencensus-contrib-grpc-metrics-0.12.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-stub\1.13.1\grpc-stub-1.13.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-auth\1.13.1\grpc-auth-1.13.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\opencensus\opencensus-api\0.15.0\opencensus-api-0.15.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\opencensus\opencensus-contrib-grpc-util\0.15.0\opencensus-contrib-grpc-util-0.15.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\20.0\guava-20.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-http\4.1.58.Final\netty-codec-http-4.1.58.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-common\4.1.58.Final\netty-common-4.1.58.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-buffer\4.1.58.Final\netty-buffer-4.1.58.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec\4.1.58.Final\netty-codec-4.1.58.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-handler\4.1.58.Final\netty-handler-4.1.58.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-resolver\4.1.58.Final\netty-resolver-4.1.58.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport\4.1.58.Final\netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.4.2\spring-boot-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.4.2\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.3\spring-core-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.3\spring-jcl-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.27\snakeyaml-1.27.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-web-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-json-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.11.4\jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.11.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.11.4.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.11.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.11.4.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.11.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.11.4.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.41\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.41\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.3\spring-web-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.3\spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring5\3.0.12.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\extras\thymeleaf-extras-java8time\3.0.4.RELEASE\thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-slf4j-impl\2.16.0\log4j-slf4j-impl-2.16.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.13.3\log4j-api-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.16.0\log4j-core-2.16.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-jul\2.16.0\log4j-jul-2.16.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.32\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\lmax\disruptor\3.3.6\disruptor-3.3.6.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-mail\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-mail-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\5.3.3\spring-context-support-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\sun\mail\jakarta.mail\1.6.5\jakarta.mail-1.6.5.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.6\aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.4.5\HikariCP-3.4.5.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.3\spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.27.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.1.3.Final\jandex-2.1.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.3\dom4j-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.3\jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.3\txw2-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.11\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.4.3\spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.4.3\spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.3\spring-orm-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.3\spring-aspects-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\4.1.1.RELEASE\spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.4.2\spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.3\spring-beans-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.3\spring-context-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.3\spring-expression-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\4.1.1.RELEASE\spring-security-config-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.3\spring-aop-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\statemachine\spring-statemachine-core\2.0.2.RELEASE\spring-statemachine-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.3\spring-tx-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-messaging\5.3.3\spring-messaging-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\oauth\spring-security-oauth2\2.0.10.RELEASE\spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.15\commons-codec-1.15.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.13\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.4.2\spring-boot-devtools-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.22\mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-swagger2\2.9.2\springfox-swagger2-2.9.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-annotations\1.5.20\swagger-annotations-1.5.20.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-models\1.5.20\swagger-models-1.5.20.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.11.4\jackson-annotations-2.11.4.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-spi\2.9.2\springfox-spi-2.9.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-core\2.9.2\springfox-core-2.9.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-schema\2.9.2\springfox-schema-2.9.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-swagger-common\2.9.2\springfox-swagger-common-2.9.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-spring-web\2.9.2\springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\plugin\spring-plugin-core\1.2.0.RELEASE\spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\plugin\spring-plugin-metadata\1.2.0.RELEASE\spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.0\commons-lang3-3.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.9.9\joda-time-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-swagger-ui\2.9.2\springfox-swagger-ui-2.9.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.4.1\liquibase-core-3.4.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\javax\ws\rs\javax.ws.rs-api\2.0.1\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\aws-java-sdk-s3\1.11.581\aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.581.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\aws-java-sdk-kms\1.11.581\aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.581.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\aws-java-sdk-core\1.11.581\aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.581.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\software\amazon\ion\ion-java\1.0.2\ion-java-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-cbor\2.11.4\jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.11.4.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\jmespath-java\1.11.581\jmespath-java-1.11.581.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\quartz-scheduler\quartz\2.2.1\quartz-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\c3p0\c3p0\0.9.1.1\c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\quartz-scheduler\quartz-jobs\2.2.1\quartz-jobs-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\firebase\geofire-java\2.2.0\geofire-java-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\maps\google-maps-services\0.2.4\google-maps-services-0.2.4.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.6\gson-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\okhttp\3.14.9\okhttp-3.14.9.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okio\okio\1.17.2\okio-1.17.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\google\android-json\0.0.20131108.vaadin1\android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\aws-java-sdk-sqs\1.11.581\aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.581.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\mvel\mvel2\2.4.4.Final\mvel2-2.4.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api-client\google-api-client\1.30.8\google-api-client-1.30.8.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\oauth-client\google-oauth-client\1.30.5\google-oauth-client-1.30.5.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\http-client\google-http-client-jackson2\1.34.1\google-http-client-jackson2-1.34.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.11.4\jackson-core-2.11.4.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\androidx\annotation\annotation\1.1.0\annotation-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web-services\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-web-services-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\messaging\saaj\saaj-impl\1.5.2\saaj-impl-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\soap\jakarta.xml.soap-api\1.4.2\jakarta.xml.soap-api-1.4.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8.3\stax-ex-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\ws\jakarta.xml.ws-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.ws-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\jws\jakarta.jws-api\2.1.0\jakarta.jws-api-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-oxm\5.3.3\spring-oxm-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\ws\spring-ws-core\3.0.10.RELEASE\spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\ws\spring-xml\3.0.10.RELEASE\spring-xml-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\wsdl4j\wsdl4j\1.6.3\wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\net\sf\supercsv\super-csv\2.4.0\super-csv-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\net\sf\supercsv\super-csv-java8\2.4.0\super-csv-java8-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\net\sf\supercsv\super-csv-dozer\2.1.0\super-csv-dozer-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\net\sf\dozer\dozer\5.4.0\dozer-5.4.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.30\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.13.1\junit-4.13.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\net\sf\barcode4j\barcode4j\2.1\barcode4j-2.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\avalon-framework\avalon-framework-impl\4.2.0\avalon-framework-impl-4.2.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.0\commons-cli-1.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\1.0\commons-lang-1.0.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant\1.7.1\ant-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant-launcher\1.7.1\ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\github\slugify\slugify\2.4\slugify-2.4.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\ibm\icu\icu4j\64.2\icu4j-64.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\opencsv\opencsv\4.1\opencsv-4.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-text\1.1\commons-text-1.1.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.3\commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.2\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\5.3.3\spring-test-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\mapstruct\mapstruct\1.4.2.Final\mapstruct-1.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\libphonenumber\libphonenumber\8.12.36\libphonenumber-8.12.36.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.vend.impact.epharmacy.Application
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52737', transport: 'socket'
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerContextFactory.isClassLoaderDependent()'
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:363)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388)
    at com.vend.impact.epharmacy.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:17)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52737', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I checked the implemation class of

[image]

how do fix this issue

Comment: Check the output of `mvn dependency:tree` if you still have some conflicting Log4J versions in there.

Comment: generally the only way NoSuchMethodError can pop up in your dependencies is if you have two different versions of the same library on classpath

Comment: Add your `pom.xml`, this can only come from an incompatible SLF4j version with the log4j version. Meaning you (or another dependency) is pulling in an older version. Ik you check your classpath you will see you are mixing Log4j 2.13.3 and Log4j 2.16.  You are also mixing different `spring-security` versions and have includes jars not needed. So I would say at first glance that your dependencies in your `pom.xml` are messy.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your classpath (the `-classpath` part in the command line) you will see the following dependencies.

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\androidx\annotation\annotation\1.1.0\annotation-1.1.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\avalon-framework\avalon-framework-impl\4.2.0\avalon-framework-impl-4.2.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\c3p0\c3p0\0.9.1.1\c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\aws-java-sdk-core\1.11.581\aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.581.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\aws-java-sdk-kms\1.11.581\aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.581.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\aws-java-sdk-s3\1.11.581\aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.581.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\aws-java-sdk-sqs\1.11.581\aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.581.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\jmespath-java\1.11.581\jmespath-java-1.11.581.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.11.4\jackson-annotations-2.11.4.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.11.4\jackson-core-2.11.4.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.11.4\jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-cbor\2.11.4\jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.11.4.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.11.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.11.4.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.11.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.11.4.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.11.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.11.4.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\firebase\geofire-java\2.2.0\geofire-java-2.2.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\github\slugify\slugify\2.4\slugify-2.4.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api-client\google-api-client-gson\1.25.0\google-api-client-gson-1.25.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api-client\google-api-client\1.30.8\google-api-client-1.30.8.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api\api-common\1.7.0\api-common-1.7.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api\gax-grpc\1.30.0\gax-grpc-1.30.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api\gax-httpjson\0.47.0\gax-httpjson-0.47.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api\gax\1.30.0\gax-1.30.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api\grpc\proto-google-cloud-firestore-v1beta1\0.26.0\proto-google-cloud-firestore-v1beta1-0.26.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api\grpc\proto-google-common-protos\1.12.0\proto-google-common-protos-1.12.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\api\grpc\proto-google-iam-v1\0.12.0\proto-google-iam-v1-0.12.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\apis\google-api-services-storage\v1-rev135-1.24.1\google-api-services-storage-v1-rev135-1.24.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\auth\google-auth-library-credentials\0.11.0\google-auth-library-credentials-0.11.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\auth\google-auth-library-oauth2-http\0.11.0\google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.11.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\auto\value\auto-value\1.4\auto-value-1.4.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\cloud\google-cloud-core-grpc\1.43.0\google-cloud-core-grpc-1.43.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\cloud\google-cloud-core-http\1.43.0\google-cloud-core-http-1.43.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\cloud\google-cloud-core\1.43.0\google-cloud-core-1.43.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\cloud\google-cloud-firestore\0.61.0-beta\google-cloud-firestore-0.61.0-beta.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\cloud\google-cloud-storage\1.43.0\google-cloud-storage-1.43.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\jsr305-3.0.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.6\gson-2.8.6.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.1.2\error_prone_annotations-2.1.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\firebase\firebase-admin\6.8.0\firebase-admin-6.8.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\20.0\guava-20.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\http-client\google-http-client-appengine\1.24.1\google-http-client-appengine-1.24.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\http-client\google-http-client-gson\1.25.0\google-http-client-gson-1.25.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\http-client\google-http-client-jackson2\1.34.1\google-http-client-jackson2-1.34.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\http-client\google-http-client-jackson\1.24.1\google-http-client-jackson-1.24.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\http-client\google-http-client\1.25.0\google-http-client-1.25.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.1\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\maps\google-maps-services\0.2.4\google-maps-services-0.2.4.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\oauth-client\google-oauth-client\1.30.5\google-oauth-client-1.30.5.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java-util\3.6.0\protobuf-java-util-3.6.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\3.6.0\protobuf-java-3.6.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\libphonenumber\libphonenumber\8.12.36\libphonenumber-8.12.36.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\ibm\icu\icu4j\64.2\icu4j-64.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\itextpdf\itextpdf\5.5.11\itextpdf-5.5.11.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\lmax\disruptor\3.3.6\disruptor-3.3.6.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\opencsv\opencsv\4.1\opencsv-4.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\okhttp\3.14.9\okhttp-3.14.9.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okio\okio\1.17.2\okio-1.17.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.11\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\sun\mail\jakarta.mail\1.6.5\jakarta.mail-1.6.5.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\messaging\saaj\saaj-impl\1.5.2\saaj-impl-1.5.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\google\android-json\0.0.20131108.vaadin1\android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.4.5\HikariCP-3.4.5.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.3\commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.0\commons-cli-1.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.15\commons-codec-1.15.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.2\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\1.0\commons-lang-1.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-auth\1.13.1\grpc-auth-1.13.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-context\1.13.1\grpc-context-1.13.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-core\1.13.1\grpc-core-1.13.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-netty-shaded\1.13.1\grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-protobuf-lite\1.13.1\grpc-protobuf-lite-1.13.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-protobuf\1.13.1\grpc-protobuf-1.13.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-stub\1.13.1\grpc-stub-1.13.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-buffer\4.1.58.Final\netty-buffer-4.1.58.Final.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-http\4.1.58.Final\netty-codec-http-4.1.58.Final.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec\4.1.58.Final\netty-codec-4.1.58.Final.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-common\4.1.58.Final\netty-common-4.1.58.Final.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-handler\4.1.58.Final\netty-handler-4.1.58.Final.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-resolver\4.1.58.Final\netty-resolver-4.1.58.Final.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport\4.1.58.Final\netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\opencensus\opencensus-api\0.15.0\opencensus-api-0.15.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\opencensus\opencensus-contrib-grpc-metrics\0.12.3\opencensus-contrib-grpc-metrics-0.12.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\opencensus\opencensus-contrib-grpc-util\0.15.0\opencensus-contrib-grpc-util-0.15.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\opencensus\opencensus-contrib-http-util\0.15.0\opencensus-contrib-http-util-0.15.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-core\2.9.2\springfox-core-2.9.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-schema\2.9.2\springfox-schema-2.9.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-spi\2.9.2\springfox-spi-2.9.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-spring-web\2.9.2\springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-swagger-common\2.9.2\springfox-swagger-common-2.9.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-swagger-ui\2.9.2\springfox-swagger-ui-2.9.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-swagger2\2.9.2\springfox-swagger2-2.9.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-annotations\1.5.20\swagger-annotations-1.5.20.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-models\1.5.20\swagger-models-1.5.20.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\jws\jakarta.jws-api\2.1.0\jakarta.jws-api-2.1.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\soap\jakarta.xml.soap-api\1.4.2\jakarta.xml.soap-api-1.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\ws\jakarta.xml.ws-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.ws-api-2.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\javax\ws\rs\javax.ws.rs-api\2.0.1\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.9.9\joda-time-2.9.9.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.13.1\junit-4.13.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.22\mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.19\byte-buddy-1.10.19.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\net\sf\barcode4j\barcode4j\2.1\barcode4j-2.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\net\sf\dozer\dozer\5.4.0\dozer-5.4.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\net\sf\supercsv\super-csv-dozer\2.1.0\super-csv-dozer-2.1.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\net\sf\supercsv\super-csv-java8\2.4.0\super-csv-java8-2.4.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\net\sf\supercsv\super-csv\2.4.0\super-csv-2.4.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\ognl\ognl\3.1.26\ognl-3.1.26.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant-launcher\1.7.1\ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant\1.7.1\ant-1.7.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.0\commons-lang3-3.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-text\1.1\commons-text-1.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.13\httpclient-4.5.13.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.14\httpcore-4.4.14.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.13.3\log4j-api-2.13.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.16.0\log4j-core-2.16.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-jul\2.16.0\log4j-jul-2.16.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-slf4j-impl\2.16.0\log4j-slf4j-impl-2.16.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\fontbox\2.0.22\fontbox-2.0.22.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\pdfbox\2.0.22\pdfbox-2.0.22.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.41\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.41\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.6\aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\attoparser\attoparser\2.0.5.RELEASE\attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.13\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.3\dom4j-2.1.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jakarta.el\3.0.3\jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.3\jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.3\txw2-2.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.27.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.1.7.Final\hibernate-validator-6.1.7.Final.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.20.0-GA\javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.1.3.Final\jandex-2.1.3.Final.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8.3\stax-ex-1.8.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.4.1\liquibase-core-3.4.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\mapstruct\mapstruct\1.4.2.Final\mapstruct-1.4.2.Final.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\mvel\mvel2\2.4.4.Final\mvel2-2.4.4.Final.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\quartz-scheduler\quartz-jobs\2.2.1\quartz-jobs-2.2.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\quartz-scheduler\quartz\2.2.1\quartz-2.2.1.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.30\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.30.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.32\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.4.2\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.4.2\spring-boot-devtools-2.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-json-2.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-mail\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-mail-2.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web-services\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-web-services-2.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-web-2.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.4.2\spring-boot-starter-2.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.4.2\spring-boot-2.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.4.3\spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.4.3\spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\plugin\spring-plugin-core\1.2.0.RELEASE\spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\plugin\spring-plugin-metadata\1.2.0.RELEASE\spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\oauth\spring-security-oauth2\2.0.10.RELEASE\spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\4.1.1.RELEASE\spring-security-config-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.4.2\spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\4.1.1.RELEASE\spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.3\spring-aop-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.3\spring-aspects-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.3\spring-beans-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\5.3.3\spring-context-support-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.3\spring-context-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.3\spring-core-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.3\spring-expression-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.3\spring-jcl-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.3\spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-messaging\5.3.3\spring-messaging-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.3\spring-orm-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-oxm\5.3.3\spring-oxm-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\5.3.3\spring-test-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.3\spring-tx-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.3\spring-web-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.3\spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\statemachine\spring-statemachine-core\2.0.2.RELEASE\spring-statemachine-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\ws\spring-ws-core\3.0.10.RELEASE\spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\ws\spring-xml\3.0.10.RELEASE\spring-xml-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\threeten\threetenbp\1.3.3\threetenbp-1.3.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\extras\thymeleaf-extras-java8time\3.0.4.RELEASE\thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring5\3.0.12.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.0.12.RELEASE\thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\xhtmlrenderer\flying-saucer-core\9.1.20\flying-saucer-core-9.1.20.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\xhtmlrenderer\flying-saucer-pdf-itext5\9.1.20\flying-saucer-pdf-itext5-9.1.20.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.27\snakeyaml-1.27.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\software\amazon\ion\ion-java\1.0.2\ion-java-1.0.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\wsdl4j\wsdl4j\1.6.3\wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar
```

There are quite some dependencies you are using and some cause issues. You are mixing log4j2 versions.

```
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.13.3\log4j-api-2.13.3.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.16.0\log4j-core-2.16.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-jul\2.16.0\log4j-jul-2.16.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-slf4j-impl\2.16.0\log4j-slf4j-impl-2.16.0.jar
```

The `log4j2-api` is version 2.13.3 while everything else is 2.16. That will blow up.

There are other dependencies for which you are mixing jars from different versions. Never mix jars from different versions of a framework (regardless of the framework).

```
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\net\sf\supercsv\super-csv-dozer\2.1.0\super-csv-dozer-2.1.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\net\sf\supercsv\super-csv-java8\2.4.0\super-csv-java8-2.4.0.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\net\sf\supercsv\super-csv\2.4.0\super-csv-2.4.0.jar
```

```
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.30\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.30.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.32\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar
```

```
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\4.1.1.RELEASE\spring-security-config-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.4.2\spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar
C:\Users\ThinkBook\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\4.1.1.RELEASE\spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
```

There might even be more, I also noticed some dependencies included twice (Jackson 1 and 2, and a google dependency pulling both of them in).

Generally all of these issues come from the fact that you are trying to outsmart the dependency management of Spring or have manually included some dependencies instead of using the starters.

Comment: it worked after I deleted my .m2 and run mvn clean install.it downloaded the correct dependencies after that i removed all the conflicting dependencies. thanks for the help

Comment: Well the issue probalby was that you didn't refresh the dependencies correctly, something in your `pom.xml` pointed to the old dependency (or you didn't refresh the project in idea after updating), else running `mvn install` would have resulted in the same.

Answer (score 0):

it work after I deleted my .m2 and run mvn clean install.it downloaded the correct dependencies after that